# how to pass/access custom data to ajax success handler

Tags: jquery

```
 for(var i =0; i < featuredItems.length; i++) {
    var item = featuredItems.eq(i).text().trim();
    alert(item); // alerts correctly
    $.ajax({
      url : "/documents/ajax/" + item,
      dataType : "text",
      success : function(data) {
        /*
          alerts the value set in the last iteration of for loop.
          I want the same value as value of item in the ajax request URL
        */
        alert (item);     
      },
    });
  }
```

How can I access value of var item appropriately in success handler?

Code above alerts the value set in the **last iteration of for loop**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to close over the `item` value:

```
for(var i =0; i < featuredItems.length; i++) {
    void function(item) {
        $.ajax({
          url : "/documents/ajax/" + item,
          dataType : "text",
          success : function(data) {
            alert (item);     
          },
        });
    }(featuredItems.eq(i).text().trim());
}
```

Comment: It's usually called closures, and a search will give you an explanation. In this instance it retains the variable value inside the closure.

Comment: @gauravjain the value of `item` was referenced in the scope of the loop, so the last value of the loop variable gets used once the loop has finished; wrapping it inside a function safeguards the value at each iteration.